# MultiDomain Rewrite for .htaccess without redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

I need to set up multilingual functionality on a website using multiple domains.
At the moment, multilingualism is implemented in links, the contents of .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(..)/?$ /?locale=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(..)?\/?select(\/{0,1})$ /?locale=$1&action=price_group [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(..)?\/?pages/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/{0,1}$ /?locale=$1&action=$2 [QSA,L]
```

This makes it possible to distinguish locale in links:

`domain1.com/en/pages/test` -> `domain1.com/?locale=en&action=test`
`domain1.com/fi/pages/test` -> `domain1.com/?locale=fi&action=test`

---

But I need to add work from several domains, and the locale parameter should be automatically substituted into the rewrite:

`domain1.com` -> `domain1.com/?locale=en`
`domain1.com/pages/test` -> `domain1.com/?locale=en&action=test`

`domain2.com` -> `domain2.com/?locale=fi`
`domain2.com/pages/test` -> `domain2.com/?locale=fi&action=test`

I tried add some rules but it works only for homepage

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[^\/]+.(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(.*)locale(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?locale=en

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[^\/]+.(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(.*)locale(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?locale=fi
```